# Matlab: Is it possible to numerically solve a system of ode's with a mixture of initial and terminal conditions?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

I'm trying to use `ode45` to solve a system of ODE's:

```
[X,Y]=  ode45(@sys,[0, T],y0);
```

where,

```
function dy = sys(t,y)

        dy(1) = f_1(y)
        dy(2) = f_2(y)
        dy(3) = f_3(y)
end
```

The problem is that the function `ode45` requires that `y0` be initial values `[y_1(0), y_2(0), y_3(0)]`, while in my system, I only have the values `[y_2(0), y_3(0), y_3(T)]` available.

Mathematically, this set of initial/terminal conditions should be enough to pin down the system, but is there any way I can work with that by `ode45` or any other functions in MATLAB?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm really interested in this question, but I'm afraid I can't help; I never encountered this sort of problem before...I know that `ode45` can integrate backwards (just use `tspan = [tend tstart]`), so you could concoct an iterative scheme to get `y_1` such that `y_3(0)` and `y_3(T)` are satisfied. Needless to say, this will likely be *very* slow and quite clumsy, but it would be a **solution**. I'll keep an eye on this one :) Could you post the equations and initial/terminal conditions?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I think I found the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After digging in the Matlab documentation for a little bit, I think the more elegant way is to use the `bvp4c` function. `bvp4c` is a function specifically designed to handle boundary value problems like this, as opposed to `ode**`, which are really for initial value problems only. In fact, there's a whole set of other functions such as `deval` and `bvpinit` in Matlab that really facilitate the use of `bvp4c`. Here's the [link to the Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/boundary-value-problems.html).

I'll post a brief (and perhaps a bit contrived) example here:

```
function [y1, y2, y3] = test(start,T)

solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,3,10), [1,1,0]);
sol = bvp4c(@odefun,@bvpbc,solinit);

tspan = linspace(start,T,100);
S = deval(sol, tspan);
y1 = S(1,:);
y2 = S(2,:);
y3 = S(3,:);

plot (tspan,y1)

figure
plot (tspan,y2)

figure
plot (tspan,y3)


%% system definition & BVCs

function dydx = odefun(t,y)
    dydx(1) = y(1) + y(2) + t;

    dydx(2) = 2*y(1) + y(2);

    dydx(3) = 3 * y(1) - y(2);
end

function res = bvpbc(y0,yT)
   res= [y0(3) yT(2) yT(3)];
end

end
```

The `test` function outputs 3 vectors of solutions points for `y1`, `y2` and `y3` respectively, and also plots them.

Here are the variable paths plotted by Matlab:
[image: y1 path]
[image: y2 path]
[image: y3 path]

Also, I found [this video by professor Jake Blanchard](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEep1-WnjlM) from WMU to be very helpful.

Comment: +2: sure looks like you licked it! I learned something new today, thanks for that :)

Comment: +2 for being surprised that @RodyOldenhuis didn't know about the BVP solver! :-) You can accept your own answer if you like.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use the [shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) to iteratively solve for the unknown initial state `y_1(0)` such that the desired final state `y_3(T)` is satisfied.

The iteration proceeds by solving a nonlinear equation `F = 0`:

```
F(y_1(0)) = Y_3(T) - y_3(T)
```

where the uppercase function `Y` is the solution obtained by integrating the ODE's *forward* in time from a set of initial conditions. The task is to guess the value of `y_1(0)` to obtain `F = 0`.

Since we're now solving a nonlinear equation, all of the usual approaches apply. Specifically you could use either bisection or Newton's method to update your guess for the unknown initial state `y_1(0)`. Note a couple of things:

1. The ODE's are integrated on `[0,T]` at each iteration of the nonlinear solve.
2. There may be multiple solutions for `F = 0`, depending on the structure of your ODE's.
3. Newton's method may converge faster than bisection, but may also be numerically unstable unless you can provide a good starting guess for `y_1(0)`.

Using existing MATLAB functions, the bounded scalar nonlinear solver `FMINBND` might be a good choice as a nonlinear solver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1: this would have been my approach, but I think @Vokram's own answer should be voted to the top :)